# Custom post type archive pagination 404

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error, custom-post-type-archives

EDIT. I found the culprit causing my issue. I had the following code to change the pagination slug to "sida" to reflect the site language. It works well for blog posts, but it does not work for custom post types. If anyone knows how I can get custom pagination slug for all post types, please chip in!

```
// Change pagination slug
function bb2_pagination_slug() {
  global $wp_rewrite;  // Get the global wordpress rewrite-rules/settings

  // Change the base pagination property which sets the wordpress pagination slug.
  $wp_rewrite->pagination_base = "sida";
}
add_action( 'init', 'bb2_pagination_slug' );
```

---

Original question:

I have a custom post type archive which works well, except when trying to go to the next page in pagination I get a 404. I can't figure out what the problem is.

I had a page with the same name as my custom post type. I removed this since I thought it might have caused the issue, but it did not help. I have flushed my rewrite rules.

If I turn of pretty permalinks it works.

The archive exists at:

> myproject.dev/om/vd-presenterar

The next page should be reachable at

> myproject.dev/om/vd-presenterar/sida/2

The paginated page does exist, I can reach it with the following URL

> myproject.dev/index.php?post_type=vd_presents&paged=2

which redirects to (I don't know how this works or why it does this):

> myproject.dev/sida/2/?post_type=vd_presents

Here is relevant part of my custom post type code:

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'om/vd-presenterar',
    'with_front'          => false,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor'),
    'taxonomies'          => array(''),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'menu_position'       => 7,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'vd_presents', $args );
```

Comment: I cannot help with rewrite rules, but just a basic check: *This is inside an `init` hook, and you have flushed your permalink?*

Comment: Yes! The custom post type is registered with:
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_vd_presents', 0 );

Also flushed permalink rules to many times now! :)

Comment: The pagination slug code you have shouldn't be - AFAIK - the issue. Try lowering the priority for it - `add_action( 'init', 'bb2_pagination_slug', 1 );`. Inspect your rewrite rules with the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), maybe it will give you clarity on this. Be sure you have successfully flushed the rules and do it again to be certain, maybe try deleting/backing up your `.htaccess` and regenerating it.

Comment: I've just seen in your comment that you are registering the post type with priority 0, you should set it up in a way that the pagination slug rewrite happens before registering the post type.

Comment: Oh well... I have to revert my last comment... @Nicolai 's answer does work but only for one language. When switching languages, the permalink structure always needs to be flushed which is no good.

Comment: @Tim Not sure what you're exactly trying to achieve, but if you want multiple languages with translated slugs then take a look at MultilingualPress – I'm not affiliated. It works with a multisite network and every language is one site of the network. Every other solution I know of, especially trying to handle multiple languages over one site, doesn't work as good, locks you in, doesn't scale and so forth. Just my 2ct based on my experience working on multiple multi language sites. Good luck.

Comment: @Nicolai You are correct. I am trying to apply this solution to a page with the WPML -Plugin. I actually mixed this up, as the question says nothing about WPML. Your solution is working perfectly for a single language. I recently used WPML for the first time and I have to say you are right. It sort of works but it is also a hassle in some cases. Thank you for the tip, I will have a look at that for future projects.